# type head searchable with name and email - tagsinput

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tags-input, typehead

I have set of data with names and emails.
How to make `type head` auto complete can be searchable with `name & email`. but the selectable value should be `email`.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="test@gmail.com" class="form-control CCContactList" />
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".CCContactList", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

        var cemaillist =  [
        {"name": "John@gmail.com", },
        {"name": "doe123@gmail.com",},
        {"name": "kevi@gmail.com", }
    ];

        $('.CCContactList').tagsinput({
            typeahead: {
                source: cemaillist.map(function(item) {
                    return item.name
                }),
                afterSelect: function() {
                    this.$element[0].value = '';
                },
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 1,
            }
        });

});
```

I want to make the source as something like below

```
var cemaillist=[ {
  "John": "John@gmail.com",},
{"Doe": "doe123@gmail.com",},
{"Kavin": "kevi@gmail.com",}];
```

so the user can easily look through using names and select the email ids.
How to make it work? Any suggestions, Please!

and I want to make the `test@gmail.com` as the default value to be selected something like below picture

[image]

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qstLbjj3/)

Comment: So you mean to say, when you search by John, Selected value should be John@gmail.com. am i right??

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal: yes, correct